# ImageMagick.MagickMissingDelegateErrorException no encode delegate for this image format CUT in C# ImageMagick

Tags: c#, imagemagick, converters, magick.net

I am trying to convert a `.jpg` to `.cut` format using C# ImageMagick. When doing that, it shows an error:

> ImageMagick.MagickMissingDelegateErrorException: 'no encode delegate
>   for this image format `CUT' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1177'

I tried the code below:

```
 using (MagickImage Image = new MagickImage(inputfolderPath))
 {
    downloadFilePath = targetFilePath + ".cut";
    Image.Format = MagickFormat.Cut;
    Image.Write(downloadFilePath);
 }
```

Would you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick can only read .cut (Dr. Halo) files. As far as I know it cannot write them. See

```
convert -list format
```

where it says:

```
CUT* CUT       r--   DR Halo
```

the r-- means read only. If it were write compatible, it would say rw-

Comment: I need the code in c# for converting .jpg format to .cut format.. Please help me..

Comment: ImageMagick cannot write to .cut as I mentioned above, not in command line and thus not in C#. It can only read .cut files. You will need to find some other tool. See http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Dr._Halo